# How to understand an expression where the (.) operator is used as an argument?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and even though I've done the basic, I still don't understand why the following result gives 4:

```
d f x = f x x
main = print ((d (.)) (d (+)) 1)
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Since no expression ever has a side effect, you can always inline expressions as much as you want. This can help you understand many of those type of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`d (.)` will result in a function `\x -> (.) x x` which takes as input `x` a function and will thus take a variable `y` and applies `x` two times, so `\x y -> x (x y)`.

The `d (+)` expression. `d (+)` is again a function that looks like `\z -> (+) z z`, or less verbose `\z -> z + z`, this is thus a function that takes as input a number `z`, and will return `z + z`.

We use this function `\z -> z + z` as variable `x` in the `\x y -> x (x y)` expression, so `d (.) (d (+))` is equivalent to `\y -> (\z -> z + z) ((\z -> z + z) y)`.

Finally we use that function with `1` as parameter, the result is thus `(\z -> z + z) ((\z -> z + z) 1)` which is equivalent to:

```
  (\z -> z + z) ((\z -> z + z) 1)
→ (\z -> z + z) (1 + 1)
→ (\z -> z + z) 2
→ (2 + 2)
→ 4
```